# Spring social login with linkedin

Tags: spring, linkedin-api, spring-social

I have configure spring social for login with facebook,twitter and linkedin connection factory.
Facebook and twitter working is fine but after login with linkedin ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection(request) gives null connection.

```
 public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
       cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(
                env.getProperty("twitter.consumer.key"),
                env.getProperty("twitter.consumer.secret")
        ));

            cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
                    env.getProperty("facebook.app.id"),
                    env.getProperty("facebook.app.secret")

                    ));


        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new LinkedInConnectionFactory(
                env.getProperty("linkedin.consumerKey"),
                env.getProperty("linkedin.consumerSecret")));


       }
```

My registration code is below here.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistrationForm(WebRequest request, Model model) {
        LOGGER.debug("Rendering registration page.");

        Connection<?> connection = ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection(request);
        RegistrationForm registration = createRegistrationDTO(connection);
        try {
            User uesr = service.registerNewUserAccount(registration);
               SecurityUtil.logInUser(uesr);
        }
        catch (DuplicateEmailException ex) {
            LOGGER.debug("An email address: {} exists.", registration.getEmail());
        }


        ProviderSignInUtils.handlePostSignUp(registration.getEmail(), request);

        return "redirect:/loginSuccess";
    }

private RegistrationForm createRegistrationDTO(Connection<?> connection) {
        RegistrationForm dto = new RegistrationForm();

        if (connection != null) {
            UserProfile socialMediaProfile = connection.fetchUserProfile();
            if(socialMediaProfile.getEmail() == null ){
                 dto.setEmail(connection.getDisplayName());
            }else{
                 dto.setEmail(socialMediaProfile.getEmail());
            }           
            dto.setFirstName(socialMediaProfile.getFirstName());
            dto.setLastName(socialMediaProfile.getLastName());

            ConnectionKey providerKey = connection.getKey();
            dto.setSignInProvider(SocialMediaService.valueOf(providerKey.getProviderId().toUpperCase()));
        }

        return dto;
    }
```

Login.jsp

```
<form method="POST" action="<c:url value="/auth/linkedin"/>">                           
                            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="http://localhost:8080/spring-social/user/register"> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="scope"
                                    value="r_emailaddress" />
                                <button class="btn btn-linkedin" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> | Connect with LinkedIn<i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></button>


 </form>
```

Here, the issue is login with linkedin dosent provide any user information because of connection object is null.
Could any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect_url shouldn't be localhost. Also make the uri relative and not absolute.
What I did was use one of my dummy blogs url, set up an alias on localhost with this url and modify the host file. Then I use this url to access the application.
For linkedIn the redirect_url must be one of the urls registered with the app.